# Как спозиционировать виджеты в BoxLayout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, qlayout

Есть **3** виджета в `QHBoxLayout`, в середине виджет с динамическим содержанием, и его надо растягивать на всю длину, а остальные два должны отображаться по контенту там.

Как это возможно реализовать?

Пробовал с использованием `addStretch()` и `setMaximumWidth()` для крайних виджетов, но не привело к нужному результату.

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны установить коэффициент растяжения при добавлении центрального макета:

```
...
self.qhboxlayout.addLayout(center_voboxlayout, stretch=1)             # <-----
...
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        tableWidget = QTableWidget(15, 5)
        time_label = QLabel("Time")
        self.clocktime = QTimeEdit()
        date_label = QLabel("Date")
        self.date_time = QDateEdit()
        combo_label = QLabel("ComboBox")
        comboBox = QComboBox()
        comboBox.addItems(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', ])
        line_label = QLabel("LineEdit")
        lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.button_1 = QPushButton("Button 1")
        self.button_2 = QPushButton("Button 2")
        self.button_2 = QPushButton("Button 3")

        left_vboxlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        left_vboxlayout.addStretch(1)
        left_vboxlayout.addWidget(time_label)
        left_vboxlayout.addWidget(self.clocktime)
        left_vboxlayout.addWidget(date_label)
        left_vboxlayout.addWidget(self.date_time)
        left_vboxlayout.addWidget(combo_label)
        left_vboxlayout.addWidget(comboBox)
        left_vboxlayout.addWidget(line_label)
        left_vboxlayout.addWidget(lineEdit)

        center_voboxlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        center_voboxlayout.addWidget(tableWidget)

        rightvboxlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        rightvboxlayout.addStretch(1)
        rightvboxlayout.addWidget(self.button_1)
        rightvboxlayout.addWidget(self.button_2)
        rightvboxlayout.addWidget(self.button_2)

        # main layout
        self.qhboxlayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.qhboxlayout.addLayout(left_vboxlayout)
        self.qhboxlayout.addLayout(center_voboxlayout, stretch=1)             # <-----
        self.qhboxlayout.addLayout(rightvboxlayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]